# How thinking sphinx object deal with belongs to and has many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using thinking sphinx (version 2.0.11) for search however I encounter some problems. Say I have a model called Product and I am using thinking sphinx to search the products. Products belong to Company and Company has many areas, an area has many companies, too. Here are some of my code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #....skip some code...

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :area

  define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes description
    indexes company(:name)
    indexes company.introduction
    indexes company.areas.area #column of model area
  end
end
```

And here is my model Company and Area

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :areaships
  has_many :areas, :through => :areaships
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areaships
  has_many :companies, :through => :areaships
  has_many :products, :through => :companies
end
```

As you can see, a product belongs to a company and a company has and belongs to many areas. How can I use thinking sphinx to search areas that of a particular product? Say the area is Paris, If I key in Paris and I should get the results of all the products that belong to some companies that belong to Paris. I've tried this for days but still can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.